# Why does this happen every time I unwrap my textures?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I've had blender for less than a week, so some of my issues are quite easy to fix, or are just plain obvious. I have been trying to texture a lighthouse model I've made, but every time I do so, the textures become extremely weird. From what I've picked up, you have to have a material for each partition you want to texture. I did that, then began to map my brick texture on the base of the lighthouse. All was looking good in texture view, but when I hit render, this happened:

[image]

Keep in mind I was not texturing the cylindrical piece below. I only have 1 material each for the 6 partitions, but somehow this is happening. Thank you for any help, and sorry for any unclear explanation.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the material settings, you will have to add more materials if you want to apply different textures to different parts of the mesh.

Comment: Can you post a copy of the .blend file you're using?  You can use PasteAll, which has a section for uploading .blend files: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure in your textures tab , The uv co - ordinates are set to UV

[image]

Make sure to UV unwarp your model before texturing!